# Update Manager Not working Fail to Download Repository Information

Tags: repository, connection, downloads, gnupg

When I try to update, I get this error:

Failed to Download your repository information
Check your internet connection

> W:GPG error: http ://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release: The following
>   signatures couldn't be     verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 4874D3686E80C6B7, W:Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found W:Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   404  Not Found E:Some index files failed to download. They have been
>   ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa

Comment: This old question (Mar 21) has been hijacked by a new user and edited into a new question (Aug 20)- this isn't supposed to happen is it?

Comment: You need to remove all the sources you listed in your question from your Software Sources. Or else, you will not be able to update anything else.

Comment: @Mik Thanks for noticing! I just saw your comment, and rolled this back. In the future, I highly recommend *flagging* to deal with this, if you cannot roll back yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 1):

The PPA requested does not have a Oneiric Release. The one that works is here:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty

You have upgraded and not edited your sources.list to reflect that change.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see right from the error, it's hitting a 404. If you punch the URL it's failing on into a browser, you'll see the same. This happens because not all PPAs are built for all versions of Ubuntu.

If you look at http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ you'll see that it only covers hardy through natty. So you either need to find a better PPA or adjust your lists settings so it pulls from the natty version (instead of oneiric).

I'd personally look for another. Looking deeper, the software here hasn't been updated for almost a year.

Answer (score 0):

open you terminal and do this

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4874D3686E80C6B7
```

and try again updating .
all the best .

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Settings** ▸ **Software Sources** ▸ **Other Software** and unchek all. Maybe this will help.